# Fancybox doesn't work if a href size not original

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, fancybox

Under this code Fancybox works **fine**:

```
<a class="fancybox img" href="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Helper", new { imagePath = Model.fullPath })">
    <img src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Helper", new { imagePath = Model.fullPath, size = "medium" })" width="600" height="600" />
</a>
```

as soon as I try to change the image size inside the href it tries to download the file rather than use Fancybox:

```
<a class="fancybox img" href="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Helper", new { imagePath = Model.fullPath, size = "medium" })">
    <img src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Helper", new { imagePath = Model.fullPath, size = "medium" })" width="600" height="600" />
</a>
```

as far as I can see my helper controller for retrieving the images treats sizes exactly the same:

```
public ActionResult GetImage(string imagePath, string size)
{
    switch(size)
    {
        case "small":
            return File(imagePath + "_small", "application/png");
            break;
        case "medium":
            return File(imagePath + "_medium", "application/png");
            break;
        default:
            return File(imagePath, "application/png");
            break;
    }
}
```

Output HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <h4><label for="Current_Version">Current Version</label></h4>
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <a class="fancybox hoverImage" href="/Helper/GetImage?imagePath=C%3A%5CTest2%5CHH%5C5988%5C342%5CG525%5CHH5988_342G525.jpg&amp;size=medium">
                <img src="/Helper/GetImage?imagePath=~%2FContent%2FImages%2FimageIcon.png" class="pull-left" width="20" height="20" />
            </a>
            <h4 style="padding-left: 30px; line-height: 0"><a href="/Multimedia/Details/1790">[4] HH5988_342G525</a></h4>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

any suggestions for the freaky behaviour or how to debug this situation properly?

Comment: how does your rendered HTML looks like?

Comment: Edited original question to include output HTML.